# Turn INFO off in PhantomJS Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium PhantomJS Webdriver to scrape a page in my C# application. I use the console a lot, so i would like to turn off the INFO messages that it constantly outputs. Do somebody have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think this string has to be added to Wasp answer:

```
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
```

So

```
    static IWebDriver CreateInfolessPhantom(string logFilePath)
{
    PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    service.LogFile = logFilePath;
    service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    return new PhantomJSDriver(service);
}
```

Comment: That worked.  It's the only thing that did. -- Also, you don't have to specify `service.LogFile` (unless you want one!), you can just set `service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;` and you're done. -- Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which helped me eventhough it's not exactly beautiful. It clears the information that is created each time i start a webdriver. I use a simple method for returning a new driver, and within it, i call a method to clear the lines created in the console and positions the console cursor at the next line.

```
public static IWebDriver GetDriver()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
        return driver;
    }
    public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
    {
        int pos = Console.CursorTop;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - i);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0,pos);
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0,Console.CursorTop-19);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me:

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
driverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
driverService.AddArgument("--webdriver-loglevel=NONE");
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my first code submission so vote it up if it helps you, or add a comment if you have improvements.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;

namespace PhantomJSExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string logFilePath = @"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\outputLog.log";
            IWebDriver driver = CreateInfolessPhantom(logFilePath);
        }

        // Prepares a PhantomJS driver that does not dislay its logs in the console window.
        // The trade-off is, you have to give it a file path to output to instead.
        static IWebDriver CreateInfolessPhantom(string logFilePath)
        {
            PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service.LogFile = logFilePath;

            return new PhantomJSDriver(service);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. -- It still spams the console with a ton of info messages.

Comment: Also, instead of hard coding the desktop path, I recommend looking it up, like so: `var logFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "output.log");`. -- Even if you know their user name, the path you specified above would be wrong sometimes; because users can put their desktop folder wherever they want, it's not set in stone.